# Example of a Lebesgue integrable function under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I need to find a sequence $(f_k)$ of Lebesgue integrable functions such that $f_k \to 0$  almost everywhere but $\lim _{k\to \infty} \int |f_k| \ne 0$.

Here is an example that I thought: $f_k(x) = g_{[ 0, k)} (1/kx) $ . Here $g_{[ 0, k)}$ is a characteristic function  . Is it right ?

Comment: Pay attention to your notations, a correct answer would be $f_k(x) = k  I_{[0, 1/k)}(x)$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{k} g_{[0,k]}$ works, notice the integral is always $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Both $$f_k = \frac{1}{k}g_{[0,k]}$$ and $$f_k =k g_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}$$ work as examples. The integrals of both are $1$, yet one goes up to "vertical infinity" while the other flattens to "horizontal infinity"

Comment: Ok, but is the fist condition of convergence almost everywhere satisfied?

Comment: @user262860 of course. The first converges everywhere on the closed ray to 0, even uniformly. The second converges to 0 everywhere but 0, where it goes to infinity